# Converting byte codes to run using a different JRE

Tags: java, bytecode

Is there a way to convert classes generated using a certain JDK version from one vendor, to those of another vendor, without decompiling them? The operating system remains the same.

Comment: If the compilers are following the spec, the bytecode should be compatible with any compliant JVM.  There are actually very few optimizations that compilers do to the bytecode, so in general they won't differ substantially.  What exact differences are you expecting/experiencing in the bytecode?

Comment: @MarkPeters I think what he's asking is whether there's a way to take a class compiled with Java 7 and convert it so that it can be run with Java 6, without decompiling the class and recompiling with compiler compliance set to Java 6.

Comment: Right.  Unless someone has gone off on their own with an oddball implementation of javac, Java bytecodes for version N should always run on version N+1, N+2, N+3...

Comment: And this should have absolutely nothing to do with the vendor -- all vendors who have a "Java(™)" implementation are required to jump through the same hoops for certification.

Comment: @Mark Peters: I am not sure about the exact differences, hence the question. Kevin Workman: The JDK versions (major version at least) are same.

Comment: If the classes complied with java 7 wont be compatible with java 6 even both compilers are from same vendor.

Comment: @Kevin Workman: The JDK versions (major version at least) are same.

Comment: As to going "downlevel", you can probably get away with simply changing the version number much of the time -- the dependencies are usually minor.  The hard one would be going from a version that expects the stack info table to one that does not -- the table would have to be extracted.  (I think this is 7 to 6, but I lost track of Java versions awhile ago.)

Comment: @HotLicks In my case, it is Java 7.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can you post these as answers?

Comment: If the class file versions are the same then there should be no problem.  Use a hex editor to look at bytes 4-7 in the .class file.  `00 00 00 33` is Java 1.7x.

Answer (score 1):

All classfiles generated by a Java X compiler will be compatible with a Java X, X+1, X+2, etc. JVM. So the only question is whether you can make it compatible with an earlier JVM than it was compiled for.

The difficulty of doing so depends on the new features introduced in that classfile version and how agreessively the compiler uses them. In the case of version 51.0 (corresponding to Java 7), it is easy to go back to 50.0 (Java 6). The only new features introduced in 51.0 were for invokedynamic support, so unless your compiler uses it, simply changing the version number in the classfile will work. The standard javac doesn't use invokedynamic, though it's conceivable that an alternative compiler could.

Note that the standard libraries also change from version to version. Code using the Try With Resources feature in Java 7 won't work on the Java 6 JVM because it requires library support.